# Is it recommended to increase the minSdkVersion as I stop using deprecated methods?

Tags: java, android, sdk

So I have an old app that has as minSdkVersion: 21 and I am changing many deprecated methods and classes for stable ones. I was wondering if now as I am using "newer" methods and classes, should I increase the minSdkVersions as those newer methods and classes could not be working in really old API level?

Comment: Depends on you if you want to support the maximum number of devices for your app out there then you may write a condition where deprecated code will be used if for example SDK is <= 25 and for rest the newer method will be used.

Comment: @MalikSaifullah if I use newer methods for every API level, what is the worst thing that could happen to old API levels? Maybe that the app crashes ? Or how could I know that those newer methods are not working in old API level? I mean, how could I know the range of API level that is not working? In your example it is 25, how could I know that?

Comment: Yes the app will crash. 
and Android Studio it self will give you a suggestion 
like this -> Call requires API level 26 (current min is 23) 
so you have to look for alternative method used before api level 26.